# Get User License field value

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to get User License field value that you can see in User setup:
[image]

Either in visualforce page or via apex.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Apex:**
You can use a below query to identify a User UserLicense of a logged in User.

```
User uObj = [Select id,Profile.UserLicense.Name from User where Id=: UserInfo.getUserId()];
System.debug('##'+uObj.Profile.UserLicense.Name);
```

**Visualforce** :
You can try below code to display User license using visual force.

```
<apex:page>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        sforce.connection.sessionId='{!$Api.Session_ID}';
        var result= sforce.connection.query("Select Name,Id,Profile.UserLicense.Name from User WHERE Id = '{!$User.Id}'"); 
        var record1 = result.getArray("records");
        var userLicenseName = record1[0].Profile.UserLicense.Name;
        alert('userLicenseName ##'+userLicenseName );
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm)

Comment: Thanks, it works! What about visualforce page, can I get the value too without writing controller?

Comment: I have this question. did you figure it out?